# Работа с моделью ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Предположим, есть некоторая модель MyModel, которая содержит поле _count типа int.

```
public class MyModel
{
    private int _count;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set { _count= value; }
    }        
}
```

Я хочу визуализировать эту модель. Через контроллер передаю туда _myModel, которую перед этим создаю. Например, так:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyModel _myModel= new MyModel ();
        return View(_myModel);
    }
```

На странице при этом находится кнопка, нажатие которой обрабатывается так:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CountUp(ViewModel model)
    {
        model.Count += 1;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Один раз это работает, а потом каждый раз создается модель по новой, в которой все значений ставятся по умолчанию. Я не понимаю, кто ее просит? Я не хочу каждый раз новую модель, я хочу, чтобы визуализировался Сount, который каждый раз будет увеличиваться по нажатию.

Comment: `return View("Index", model);` в методе `CountUp`

Comment: добавьте в вопрос содержимое вью `Index` и `CountUp`

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит потому, что вы не сохраняете текущее состояние модели. ASP не находя в форме никаких значений создает модель, заполняя поля значениями по умолчанию.

---

Для решения добавьте в форму скрытое поле для дальнейшей передачи, но при таком подходе данные легко поменять, открыв html.

**View**

```
@model MyModel

...
<div>Count: @Model.Count </div>
...

@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerName", "CounUp", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Count)
   <button type="submit">Увеличить значение</button>
}
...
```

И еще. Вы говорите

> Предположим, есть некоторая модель MyModel

А принимаете

> `public ActionResult CountUp(ViewModel model)`

Следовало бы заменить на

```
public ActionResult CountUp(MyModel model)
```

Comment: То есть, проблема в том, что не меняется поле? Но у меня задано поле в представлении. Я ведь не должна изменять его напрямую? Я думала, что смысл именно в том, чтобы изменять модель, а вместе с этим изменялось бы представление?

Comment: @Regen я ваш вопрос из комментария не совсем понимаю. Не могли бы вы его уточнить ?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте view: CountUp, каждый ли раз кнопка отправляет POST запрос.

По идее получается так:

1. Сначала отправляется GET запрос по роуту Controller.Index и получает view: Controller/Index.cshtml
2. Затем вы жмёте кнопку и попадаете на роут Controller.CountUp и получает view: Controller/CountUp.cshtml
3. На этом шаге вы видите увеличенный номер на 1.
4. Скорее всего view CountUp.cshtml делает get запрос по роуту Controller.Index

Comment: Кнопка обрабатывается каждый раз. Я проходила отладчиком весь процесс. Но в метод обработки нажатия кнопки приходит модель со значениями по умолчанию, а не измененная предыдущим нажатием кнопки. Т.е., приходит Count, равный 0, увеличивается, на странице это видно. Затем при нажатии снова приходит модель в метод с нулевым Count, и так далее. Каждый раз получается 1.

Comment: Значит на странице с которой происходит запрос нету этой модели.
Как выглядит post запрос (в строке адреса)?