# Изменение значений в представлении ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Есть одно представление и одна модель данных. Модель заполняется значениями по умолчанию (БД нет), которые отображаются затем в представлении. Я хочу по нажатиям кнопок в представлении изменять имеющуюся модель и значения соответствующих контролов в представлении. Но при каждом запросе создается новый экземпляр контроллера и модель заполняется значениями по умолчанию. Как сохранять данные и передавать их снова в представление?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с моделью ASP.NET MVC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662801/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%8e-asp-net-mvc)